# Удалить id из URL

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Подскажите, пожалуйста, «регулярку» для перенаправления с

```
site.ru/117-avtoelektronika.html
```

на

```
site.ru/avtoelektronika
```

и с

```
site.ru/telefony-apple/957-telefon-apple-iphone-5c-8gb-blue.html
```

на

```
site.ru/telefony-apple/telefon-apple-iphone-5c-8gb-blue
```

То есть, если после слеша идут цифры и тире, то удалить их, и всегда удалять .html на конце.

Comment: Смутило слово "перенаправления". Это вы не .htaccess настраиваете? Опишите, откуда берутся эти URL

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Заменить

```
/\d+-(.*)\.html$
```

на

```
/$1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(preg_match('#(?:([/])[\d]+[-]|\.html)#', $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI])){
    header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
    header('Location: '.preg_replace('#(?:([/])[\d]+[-]|\.html)#', '$1', $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]));
    exit();
}
```